# Assign elements of a dataframe from skills registered in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have the following problem, on the one hand I have a dataframe with two columns, the name of the people and the technologies they handle:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

censo = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Uriel","Ricardo","Rodrigo","Arion"], "Tec":[("Sas, Python"),("Python, Pyspark"),("Python, Tableau"),("Excel")]})
censo.head(10)
```

The output is something like this:

[image]

Then I have another dataframe that has two other columns: requests and technology that request requires:

```
tec = pd.DataFrame({"Request":["001","002","003","004"], "Tec":["Python","Sas","Tableau","Excel"]})
tec.head(5)
```

Whose output is the following:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to create a column called "Assignment" in which appears the name of the person from the first dataframe that makes the best fit with the technology requested in the request.

I tried converting the values of the technologies to dummies and then trying to make the match, but I'm not even close to what I need.

```
 a = censo['Tec'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
 a = a.drop_duplicates()
 a = a.loc[~(a==0).all(axis=1)]
 censo_ = pd.concat([censo,a], axis = 1)
censo_.head()
```

[image]

```
tec['Assignment'] = censo['Name'].apply(lambda x: 'Python' in x)
tec.head()
```

Any ideas what I could do to fix this problem?

First of all, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `str.get_dummies`

```
out = censo.join(censo['Tec'].str.get_dummies(','))
```

Update

```
out = censo.assign(Tec=censo.Tec.str.split(',')).explode('Tec').\
            merge(tec,how='left').groupby(['Request','Tec'])['Name'].agg(list)
Request  Tec   
001      Python    [Ricardo, Rodrigo]
002      Sas                  [Uriel]
004      Excel                [Arion]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, that made my code much cleaner and more efficient. However, what I want to do is in the dataframe called "tec", create a column called "Assignment" that will return the name of the person with the best profile. For example, in the request "004" that someone who knows "Excel" asks, who should appear because he is the only one with that skill is "Arion"

Comment: @RicardoJ.MartínezSuástegui check the update

Comment: Just one more thing how can I make that object a dataframe?

Comment: Forget it, was really so easy. I didn´t know that a cast like this works:

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df.head()

Comment: @RicardoJ.MartínezSuástegui out = out.reset_index()